# Deducing Arguments Failure for Variadic Template Function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

This seems like a standard case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template <typename... T>
using VType = vector<tuple<T...>>;

template <typename... T>
void Foo(const T&... t, VType<T...>* v) {
    v->push_back(std::make_tuple(t...));
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    VType<string, string> foo;
    Foo(string("asdf"), string("qwerty"), &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

If you explicitly tell the compiler `Foo<string, string>` it works fine, it fails to deduce with:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, VType<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >*)’`

This function works as expected:

```
template <typename... T>
void Bar(const std::tuple<T...> t, VType<T...>* v) {
  v.push_back(t); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types of a variadic list of arguments can be deduced only in last position.

So

```
template <typename... T>
void Foo(VType<T...>* v, const T&... t) {
    v->push_back(std::make_tuple(t...));
}
```

works because the `t ...` arguments are in last position where

```
template <typename... T>
void Foo(const T&... t, VType<T...>* v) {
    v->push_back(std::make_tuple(t...));
}
```

give error because `t...` isn't in last position.

Solution: modify `Foo()` to receive the pointer to vector argument `v` in first position and call `Foo()` as follows

```
Foo(&foo, string("asdf"), string("qwerty"));
```

Comment: _The types of a variadic list of arguments can be deduced only in last position_. Actually there are exceptions to this rule, as an example something like `template<typename... T> int foo(T..., int i = 0) { return i; }` works.

Comment: @skypjack Define "works". It still can't be deduced for more than zero template arguments in your example. `foo("test")` will yield a compile error. This is exactly the problem described here.